# Get ID of current taxonomy in register_rest_field

Tags: categories, rest-api, term-meta

I have a term field created with types plugin and attached to the "category" taxonomy. I need to get this field in the api rest. You cant get the termmeta in types plugin like this

```
types_render_termmeta($slug_term, array("term_id" => $term_id));
```

I don't know how to get current category id in `register_rest_field` function.

```
  register_rest_field( 'category', 'color', array( 
     'get_callback' => function() {

        $term_id = "DONT KNOW HOW TO GET IT";

        $color = types_render_termmeta('color-de-categoria', array("term_id" => $term_id));

        return $color;
    }        
));
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_callback` part is generated within the [`WP_REST_Controller::add_additional_fields_to_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/add_additional_fields_to_object/) method with:

```
$object[ $field_name ] = call_user_func( 
    $field_options['get_callback'], 
    $object, 
    $field_name, 
    $request, 
    $this->get_object_type() 
);
```

That means the callback has four input arguments:

```
'get_callback' => function ( $object, $field_name, $request, $object_type ) {
    // ...
}
```

and for the requested *category* object, we can get the term id with:

```
$term_id = $object['id'];
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot @birgie!! adding $object to get_callback' => function($object) did the trick !